# IBAction doesn't work on a custom view cell

Tags: ios, xcode5, ibaction, custom-cell

This is my first post on StackOverflow !
I'm working on a projet made by someone else one or two years ago. I'm a really beginner with xcode, ios7 and so on, so i will try to explain my problem correctly...
I'm working on a custom cell that contain labels and buttons. One of this button was not made by me and works fine. The others are made by me and doesn't work at all. This is not my first app but it's the first time that I see that ! Every links (button <-> event) are correctly done, there is nothing invisible in front of my button, I set a colored background to be sure to touch the button... nothing !
If it can help : I put a breakpoint in my IBAction and I never pass through it...
What can have I missed ?
Thanks in advance for your answer !

Comment: Show us some code. How you are adding event to that button, button configuration, etc. Otherwise its hard to help you.

Comment: show some code. what u have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my bad. I finally found where the problem was.
By trying anything I set my new button to fill every space in the cell. And I detected a kind of "edge" in it : above my button work and below it doesn't !
Then, I remember that I had to enlarge cell to put my new buttons in it. In this new space, tap wasn't detected. So I looked through the code I found a place where 
`heightForRowAtIndexPath`
was set at 90. That was the limit of the edge...
I set my new height and everything works fine

It's really a pain to have to work with a someone else code (without comment of course!)

Thanks to everybody !